# knit2html rglplot not showing

Tags: r, knitr, rgl

I'm using knitr's `knit2html` function to generate a html with embedded rgl plot (interactive)
with the commands

`>knit2html("myfile.rmd")`

my R markdown:

````
```{r setup}
library(rgl)
knit_hooks$set(webgl = hook_webgl)
```

```{r testgl, webgl=TRUE}
x <- sort(rnorm(1000))
y <- rnorm(1000)
z <- rnorm(1000) + atan2(x,y)
plot3d(x, y, z, col=rainbow(1000))
```
````

`sessionInfo()` gives `rgl_0.95.1227` and `knitr_1.9.4`

I'm not able to see the 3D plot in the html generated. 
Checked the html javascript console and says that rglclass is not declared.

It was not included in the html file. neither was `CanvasMatrix.js` generated.
What am I missing?

I see that knitr's `hook_webgl` wrapper around rgl's `writeWebGL`

```
writeWebGL(dir = dirname(name), filename = name, template = NULL, 
        prefix = prefix, snapshot = FALSE, commonParts = commonParts)
```

It seems that the `commonParts` arguement has been set to false?

function `hook_webgl` from `knitr`

```
function (before, options, envir) 
{
if (before || rgl::rgl.cur() == 0) 
    return()
name = tempfile("rgl", ".", ".html")
on.exit(unlink(name))
dpi = options$dpi/options$fig.retina
rgl::par3d(windowRect = 100 + dpi * c(0, 0, options$fig.width, 
    options$fig.height))
Sys.sleep(0.05)
prefix = gsub("[^[:alnum:]]", "_", options$label)
prefix = sub("^([^[:alpha:]])", "_\\1", prefix)
rgl::writeWebGL(dir = dirname(name), filename = name, template = NULL, 
    prefix = prefix, snapshot = FALSE, commonParts = commonParts)
commonParts <<- FALSE
res = readLines(name)
res = res[!grepl("^\\s*$", res)]
paste(gsub("^\\s+", "", res), collapse = "\n")
}
```

Comment: I forked the knitr package and changed function in `hook.extra.R` from 

`rgl::writeWebGL(dir = dirname(name), filename = name, template = NULL, 
    prefix = prefix, snapshot = FALSE, commonParts = commonParts)
commonParts <<- FALSE`

to 

`rgl::writeWebGL(dir = dirname(name), filename = name, template = NULL, 
    prefix = prefix, snapshot = FALSE, commonParts = TRUE)` and it works...

Comment: For the record: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/969

Comment: you should write it up as an answer end mark it correct.